# geo-location taxonomy of public / commercial location types? (for mapping from postal addresses)

Tags: geolocation, data-mining, google-places-api

Is there a standard or widely-used taxonomy in the market-research, advertising, or retail industry to classify public or commercial locations?  We want to map from the postal address of a public or commercial location (e.g. school, hospital, factory, office park, etc.) into a taxonomy of locations (e.g. "schools", "hospitals", etc.).  Instead of inventing our own taxonomy, we'd like to use an exisitng one if possible.

Doing the address->taxonomy mapping is a related but separate problem. For now, we're just looking for a taxonomy and we're assuming we're going to do the mapping ourselves, although if a great commercial geo-location mapping service uses a particular taxonomy, we'd probably favor that one!

Here's more details about our use case:

Our customers operate small food stores inside public or commercial locations like office parks, schools, hospitals, airports, etc.  We provide algorithmically-driven merchandising recommendations, meaning we help retailers select which products to sell in their stores and how much space to devote to each product.

We want to use location type in our algorithms, because the products that sell best in stores in hospitals, for example, are different products from those that sell well in high schools or factories.  We know the postal address of every location. Most of our locations are in the US or Canada, so a North-America-only solution is OK although not ideal.

We're hoping a taxonomy would look something like the list below:

```
Office
   High Income (e.g. law/medical office)
   Low Income (e.g. Call Center)
Industrial
   Factory
   Repair/Maintenance Shop
Hospital
Hotel
School
   College
   Secondary School
   Middle School
   Primary School
   Other School (e.g. driving school)
Transportation
   Airport
   Bus Station
   Train Station
Stadium
Retail
   Mall
   Large Retail (e.g. department store)
   Small Retail
   Supermarket
   Other Retail
Religious (church, mosque, etc.)
Government (excluding schools)
   Prison
   Courthouse
   Other Government
```

If there are several standards in use, then is there one tied to widely-used, affordable service(s) for mapping US postal addresses into the taxonomy?

Here's a few options I found so far, although I don't know how much these are used in geo-located market research:

- [NAICS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Industry_Classification_System), [GICS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Industry_Classification_Standard), and other [industry classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_classification) schemes: not exactly what we need because they focuses on the type of business, not necessarily a place. Places like stadiums are tough to model with these kinds of taxonomies.
- [Google Places](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/supported_types.html): The taxonomy meets our needs pretty well. But we can't use Google's service (no private, commercial use allowed) and a quick test showed that Google only had entries half our locations. So it's not clear that using Google's taxonomy makes sense, if there's better industry support for a different one.

Comment: To clarify on Google's licensing, commercial use is allowed, but not private use unless you purchase the Maps API for Business (formerly known as Maps API Premier). Also, you can add additional places to Google either through Map Maker or through Google Places for Business.